# Can we do global setting with i18n in webapp2?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have a category list, and I'd like use it with i18n so that I can change the language by locale.

My python code is as following:

```
from webapp2_extras import i18n

category_list = {}
category_list['bikes'] = {'value': i18n.gettext('CATEGORY_BIKES')}

class CategoriesHandler(BaseHandler):
    """List categories"""
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        """List all categories"""
        self.response.write(self.json_output(category_list))
```

And it will cause the error:

```
  File "/Users/user/Developer/GAE/project/CategoriesHandler.py", line 11, in <module>
    category_list['bikes'] = {'value': i18n.gettext('CATEGORY_BIKES')}
  File "/Users/user/Developer/GAE/project/webapp2_extras/i18n.py", line 713, in gettext
    return get_i18n().gettext(string, **variables)
  File "/Users/user/Developer/GAE/project/webapp2_extras/i18n.py", line 894, in get_i18n
    request = request or webapp2.get_request()
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2/webapp2.py", line 1720, in get_request
    assert getattr(_local, 'request', None) is not None, _get_request_error
AssertionError: Request global variable is not set.
```

However if I move the category_list into the class get method, everything is fine.

```
class CategoriesHandler(BaseHandler):
    """List categories"""
    def get(self, **kwargs):
        """List all categories"""
        category_list = {}
        category_list['bikes'] = {'value': i18n.gettext('CATEGORY_BIKES')}
        self.response.write(self.json_output(category_list))
        pass
```

The problem is that I need to separate category_list to another config file so that I can maintain my code easily. Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try gettext_lazy instead, which won't do actual translation lookup until later (when you also know which language you want to translate to).

A very common convention is

```
from webapp2_extras.i18n import _lazy as _
category_list['bikes'] = {'value': _('CATEGORY_BIKES')}
```

Comment: Great answer! That solves my problem..but I got another problem: I need to transform category_list to JSON object using json.dumps(), but it seems category_list will no longer be JSON serializable after using ugettext_lazy. Is there any way to handle this? Thanks for your answer anyway!

Comment: Make a defaultencode method that you pass into json.dumps as default argument. Check if passed in object is a lazy translatable object, and in that case do str(object) or unicode(object) if translations are hooked up properly.